# openGL: Losing details from a loaded obj file

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm loading a .obj file into my program (without a .mtl file).
In the vertex shader, I have this:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 in_color;
```

and my vertex structure looks like this:

```
struct VertexFormat {
    glm::vec3 position; 
    glm::vec3 color;    
    glm::vec3 normal;   
    glm::vec2 texcoord; 
    VertexFormat() { every atribute is glm::vec3(0, 0, 0); }
    VertexFormat(glm::vec3 _position, glm::vec3 _normal, glm::vec2 _texcoord, glm::vec3 _color) {
        position    = _position;
        normal      = _normal;
        texcoord    = _texcoord;
    //  color       = glm::vec3(texcoord, cos(texcoord.x + texcoord.y));
        color       = normal;
    }
}
```

Because I don't have a .mtl file, the color attribute depends on the other vertex attributes.

If I let `color = glm::vec3(texcoord, cos(texcoord.x + texcoord.y));`, the object loses some of the details (like a human face is just an ellipsoid).

This does not happen when I let `color = normal;`.

I want the color to not depend only on the normal attribute because then every object is colored as a rainbow.

Any idea why and how can I make it work?

### EDIT:

This is an object with `color = normal`:

[image]

And this is with `color = glm::vec3(texcoord, cos(texcoord.x + texcoord.y));`:

[image]

The only things changed between the two pictures are the fact that I commented `color = normal;` and decommented the other.

Comment: It is not quite clear what do you want to achieve. Does `color = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)` or just assigning same white (or whatever) color in fragment shader will do the trick? All things will be white then =)

Comment: To get more than just the silhouette of details, you generally account for the surface normal and the lighting direction. Without seeing your .obj file, it's impossible to know if the texcoords vary, which would be needed to get different colours. Er, what _do_ you want the vertex colours to depend on? Have a look for a phong-shading vertex/fragment shader pair is my suggestion

Comment: @enhzflep I can't use lighting. I will post some photos to show the difference between the two color usage.

Comment: I you can't use lighting in the shader then do the lighting in the parser. Choose a light vector ad made a color based on the dot product with the normal.

Comment: @tas92 - okay fine. But again, what _do_ you want the colour to depend on? I.e dont tell us what you _dont_ want (the colour to depend on the normal) tell us what you _do_ want.

Comment: @ilmale - I would prefer to not use lighting at all. I don't understand why without lighting the first works (shows the details), while the other one doesn't.

Comment: @enhzflep - well, I want the colors to depend on texcoord.

Comment: In that case, it's probably worth updating your question. As for why there is so little surface detail? Easy - the UVs range from <0,0> to <1,1> - on a well UV-mapped model (one that doesn't exhibit stretching of the texture) that's a constant rate of variation, that doesn't take into account the changes you'd expect around areas whose surface normal changes rapidly, like the eyes and mouth, for instance. You realize that you can precompute the lighting - i.e calculate colours of the vertices yourself and avoid entirely openGL's lighting model. Many games have done just this. Why not lighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comment you wrote

> I would prefer to not use lighting at all. I don't understand why without lighting the first works (shows the details), while the other one doesn't

Perceived details depend on the color contrast in the final picture. The stronger the contrast, the stronger the detail (there's a strong relation to so called spatial frequencies as well).

Anyway, creased, edges, bulges, etc. in the mesh create a strong local position depending variation of the surface normal, which is what you see. In mathematical terms you could write this as

```
|| ∂/∂r n(r) ||
```

where n denotes the normal and r denotes the position, which becomes very large for creases and such.

The variation of a color depending position `c(r)` however would be

```
|| ∂/∂r c(r) ||
```

But since c(r) depends on only r and no local features c acts just like a constant and the local spatial variation in color is constant as well, i.e. has no strong features.

Essentially it means that you can make details visible only based on derivatives of surface features such as the normals.

The easiest way to do this is to use illumination. But you can use other methods as well, for example you can calculate the local variations of the normals (giving you the curvature of the surface) and make stronger curves areas brighter. Or you perform post processing on the screen space geometry, applying something like a first or second order gradient filter.

But you will not get around to apply math to it. There's no such thing as a free meal. Also don't expect people to write code for you without being clear what you actually want.

Comment: :thumbsup: My ++. So much more eloquently put than I was able.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thing I undestood why it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry that I lead you to think that I wanted code; I said "and how can I make it work" because I thought that I needed to apply some glm::normalize or something like this. I saw that behavior and I didn't understood why. Anyway, thanks again. I think that, after all, I'll implement lighting.